# Setting and retrieving values from an array with Checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to place a value and retrieve it later on

```
$fruits = array("Watermelon", "Lime", "Lemon");
$result = count($fruits);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $result) {
echo "<br>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='fruit[]' value='$fruits[$i]'>";

echo "$fruits[$i]";
$i++;
}
```

The first set I assigned the fruit to the value per the array, the code below is supposed to set the values in the if statement and compare them to the checkbox. If I put in the fruit by name it works e.g. "Watermelon" works but "$fruits[0]" does not.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

if(isset($_POST["fruit"])){
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $result) {

       if(in_array('$fruits[$i]', $_POST['fruit'])){
            echo "It works!";
            $i++;
        } else {

        $i++;
        } 
    } 
} else {
            echo "choose a box";
            $i = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with `foreach()`(if you want to).

```
if(isset($_POST['fruit'])) {
    foreach($_POST['fruit'] as $fruit) {
        $fruits[] = $fruit;
    }
    if(!empty($fruits)) {
        echo 'It Works.!';
    } else {
        echo "choose a box";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I've spent hours trying to do this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: So when I do this code and write  "echo '$fruit'; I get only the last selected boxes value written out. Should I be placing the selected values into an Array?

Comment: Please write `echo $fruits;`, it will give you all selected fruits. And avoid quotes `''` around **variables**.

Answer (score 0):

You use `$i++` in work condition so if will increase $i to 1 until last index of `$fruits` ,if `$fruits` last index is not exist in `$_POST` it will nothing display.. use exit can be display.

```
if(isset($_POST["fruit"])){
    $i = 0;
    while($i < $result) {
       if(in_array($fruits[$i],$_POST['fruit'])){
            echo "It works!";
            exit;
        } else {    
        $i++;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Also no need to quote in your array...

```
if(in_array('$fruits[$i]', $_POST['fruit'])) //remove ''
```